# Simulating app view in iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an app installed in iPhone 6s. I would like to see how it looks in iPhone 5. My app is an in-house app and not yet distributed in iStore.

Is there anyway I can simulate the view in iPhone 5, using my app installed in iPhone 6s. I do not have an iPhone 5 device.

Comment: same, same, but on a but smaller screen – however you could test the auto-layout and constraints in Xcode by choosing different idiom in IB, and you can see any potential glitch in the app (you can also test the app on the simulator using different idioms).

Comment: Why don't you just use the simulator provided by xcode? and select iPhone 5/SE

Comment: Don't forget about Interface Builder's Preview accessory view, which allows you to see what a view controller will look like on multiple device sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply No you can't.

1.If you wanna check into other models, you can use Interface builder preview provided by Xcode.

2.If app is an House-app or any (holding IPA file on app) & if you have other model device then probably you can use [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) helps developers to deploy Development and In-house applications directly to the devices.